# Can a container apply to a single max-width media query?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox as well as media queries to set max and min widths for my elements. So far it's going fine, but to get a layout I wanted at min-width:1000px I needed to create an extra container for two elements to be in a column layout within the row layout applied to the rest of the page.

This works, but once the width is below 1000px I want the container to go away and for the normal rules to apply to the elements affected. Aside from trying to set the container to `display:none` (which predictably just removes the elements altogether) I'm not sure how to fix this. It's pretty specific so I haven't found an answer to it yet.

Here's how it looks above 1000px:

[image: 1000px+]

Below 1000px:

[image: -1000px]

And iPhone/Tablet sized(largContainer disappears behind the #content container:

[image: -760px]

```css
#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.articleImage {
  order: 1;
  width: 48%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 250px;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

article a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(13%, 50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-shadow: black 1px 1px 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.reasons {
  order: 2;
  border: solid 1px #f77f00;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .largeContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 26.1%;
  }
  .articleImage {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  article {
    font-size: small;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  article a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate(5%, 50%);
  }
  .reasons {
    order: 2;
    font-size: .85em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px #f77f00;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="largeContainer">
    <div class="articleImage">
      <article>
        <a href="https://www.theodysseyonline.com/20-reasons-should-eat-mac-cheese" target="_blank">20 Reasons You Should Eat
                          <br>Mac and Cheese Right Now</a>
        <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.TRKuAA8Nt1iBs76N6HDM-AAAAA?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Fabulous Mac">

      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="reasons">
      <h3>What's so Great about Mac and Cheese??</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>It's a wholesome dish</li>
        <li>Cheese is good for the soul</li>
        <li>Just look at it</li>
        <li>It'll make you the star of any potluck</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, it's a landing page about Mac and Cheese! I'd like this example to display the elements in a row like the primary container when it's under 1000px, but it's not resetting even though .largeContainer isn't in the main CSS code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't find it clear what you wanna do. Do you simply want to "remove" a container under a certain width ?

Comment: @Dolotboy I only want the extra container to apply when the screen is above a certain width, yes. In the included images the first one is exactly what I want for above 1000px, but then it keeps that layout as it gets smaller even though I didn’t include the extra container in the other sections of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this same question at some point:

I was hoping to not have to add extra media queries to adjust the layout at specific widths, but that's the only solution I could find. I added queries directed only at the affected elements and made the small changes to keep it as simple as possible.

[Above 1000px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp2fb.jpg)

[760px-1000px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlxFA.png)

[662px-760px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCbvs.png)

[Below 662px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whka5.png)

```css
.largeContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.articleImage {
  order: 1;
  width: 48%;
}

.reasons {
  order: 2;
  width: 48%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .largeContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 28.1%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .articleImage {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .reasons {
    order: 2;
    font-size: .823em;
    width: 93%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .largeContainer {
    display: flex;
  }
  .reasons {
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:662px) {
  .largeContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .articleImage {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  .reasons {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="largeContainer">
  <div class="articleImage">
    <article>
      <a href="https://www.theodysseyonline.com/20-reasons-should-eat-mac-cheese" target="_blank">20 Reasons You Should Eat
                        <br>Mac and Cheese Right Now</a>
      <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.TRKuAA8Nt1iBs76N6HDM-AAAAA?pid=ImgDet&rs=1" alt="Fabulous Mac">
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="reasons">
    <h3>What's so Great about Mac and Cheese??</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>It's a wholesome dish</li>
      <li>Cheese is good for the soul</li>
      <li>Just look at it</li>
      <li>It'll make you the star of any potluck</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I can't get RID of .largeContainer in other queries since it's in the HTML, I can just adjust it to make it work in the different widths. Hopefully that helps somebody else! *Photos included to give complete picture of the layout*